# Azure DevOps Artifacts - Retention policy clarification

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I am trying to understand how retention policies of Artifacts feed work.

I read through this article

[Azure Artifacts/Delete and recover packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/delete-and-recover-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=universal#delete-packages-from-azure-artifacts-feeds)

but it is not clear whether retention policies apply only when "the maximum number of versions to keep" has been reached or generally for all versions. It is also not clear if the latest versions will be always kept, regardless of the retention policies.

For example, I set up a feed with the following retention policies:

```
Maximum number of versions per package: 10
Days to keep recently downloaded packages 2
```

[Retention policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te4t8.png)

Then I created a pipeline which uploads build artifacts as universal packages to the feed.
As you can see from the following picture

[Package versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4kO6.png)

old package versions are still available for download even if they exceeded the "max days to keep" value.

Could someone please clarify how Azure Devops Artifacts retention policies actually work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When enabled `days to keep recently downloaded packages`, packages will only be deleted by retention policies if they have not been downloaded within the number of days set. Is it possible that someone in your team still use the old versions?

Comment: No, nobody is using them. If you take a look at the last picture I posted, you can see that for almost all package versions the number of downloads is 0 and those package versions have for sure exceeded the number of days to keep.

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT, thanks for your support. Have you had any chance to test it? Any update?

Comment: I've tested with a package which only have one version, and this version is not deleted by retention policy. If you publish versions  > `maximum number of versions`, will the retention policy work?

Comment: Yes, that works, the latest versions are deleted if the maximum is exceeded

Comment: I meant, the oldest versions get deleted but only if the package has exceeded the maximum number of versions, regardless of the "days to keep" setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my tests, I've found how Artifact Retention policy works. When the package versions exceed `Maximum number of versions per package`, the policy will check the exceeded versions, if there are versions downloaded during `Days to keep recently downloaded packages`, the policy won't delete them, otherwise the exceeded versions will be deleted.

For example:

I have two feeds with 16 versions of a package, both settings as below:

[image]

If I never download any versions, the exceeded oldest ones will be deleted:

[image]

If I download the oldest two, then the oldest two won't be deleted temporarily, they will be deleted after `Days to keep recently downloaded packages`:

[image]

Comment: So, in other words (and please correct me if I am wrong), a package version will be deleted only if the total number of package versions exceed the "Maximum number of versions per package", otherwise they will be kept forever, even if nobody has ever downloaded any of them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. One last question: from your perspective, is that a bug or the intended behavior by design?

Comment: In my opinion, it's an expected behavior. `Maximum number of versions per package` and `Days to keep recently downloaded packages` are combinatorial policy. Image you publish a version of a package, and don't use it yet, then it's deleted by the policy...it seems unreasonable.

Comment: Yes, it is, even if from the documentation it is not clear. It would be nice to have a forced eviction policy though, without the need of reaching the maximum number of versions per package, but now I am talking about a new feature request.